# Aggregate values obtained from a callback function in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduction

I have a class that exposes a way to enumerate some values (which may not be stored nicely in an array or other built-in collection):

```
class DataStore {
  constructor(values) {
    this.values = values;
  }
  forEachData(callback) {
    // the callback is invoked with items specific to the logic of DataStore
    callback(0);
    callback(1);
    for (const x of this.values) {
      callback(x);
    }
    for (const x of this.values) {
      callback(2 * x);
    }
  }
}
```

In another function that uses this class, I would like to perform some kind of aggregation (i.e. reduction) operation on the values returned by the callback.  Is there a concise way to express this using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) or some other built-in way without doing the reduction manually?

```
// Inside my function
const data_store = ...; // DataStore object
const aggregate_op = (accumulator, current_value) => Math.min(accumulator, f(current_value));

// I'm wondering if there is a built-in language or library feature that does this kind of reduction:
let answer = 0;
data_store.forEachData(x => {
  answer = aggregate_op(answer, x);
});
```

Note: It is simple enough to do the reduction manually as above, but arguably, array reduction is also very simple without using Array.prototype.reduce():

```
const arr = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
let answer = 0;
arr.forEach(x => {
  answer = aggregate_op(answer, x);
});
```

Comment: Are you collecting the results of the callback somehow or somewhere?

Comment: Also, your last snippet is a bit nonsensical - inside the `forEach` you're overwriting the variable that holds the array you are operating on?

Comment: @VLAZ Nope.  I just want to find the 'best' value over all the items in the `DataStore`, where 'best' is defined by the aggregation function.

Comment: @VLAZ  Oops.  I've changed the last snippet.

Comment: I still don't get what is the ultimate goal here. `answer = aggregate_op(answer, x)` in a `forEach` still appears like reinventing `.reduce`. The only issue you have is that you never capture the results of the callback to be able to somehow act on them. So, unless your callback keeps track of all the results, you probably need to either add a different operation to `DataStore` or change `forEachData` to capture the results.

Comment: You can add another function to your class that calls `forEachData` and returns an array.

Comment: @VLAZ  I'm hoping that there exists some built-in function that can be called like `reduce(data_store.forEachData, 0, aggregate_op)` and will return the aggregated answer.

Comment: @Bernard but `forEachData` doesn't *return* anything. You never capture the output of each callback execution. That's a fundamental problem with the code presented. If you don't want to add the ability to capture the result in some fashion, you'd need to pass a stateful stateful that collects each result itself. Which is quite annoying, although you could maybe generalise it to a generic wrapper that gives you an array of all results and allows you to then act on those...although you're better off adding this functionality directly into `DataStore`.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed implement your own `reduce` function. And you've almost done it:

```
class DataStore {
  constructor(values) { /* constructor logic */ }

  forEachData(callback) { /* forEach logic */}

  reduce(callback, initialValue) {
    let value = initialValue;
    this.forEachData(function(x){
      value = callback(value, x);
    });

    return value;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
let answer = data_store.reduce(aggregate_op, 0);
```

Is there a way to do this automatically without re-inventing the wheel? Sort of. It depends on how you manage your values. You can simply inherit form `Array`:

```
class DataStore extends Array { /* ... */ }
```

Here you cannot write your own `forEachData` method, instead use `forEach` and don't hardcode the `0` and `1` value, instead actually insert it in the object's internal array of data. Also this will mean you must stick to array semantics - no string index, no sparse indexes etc.

If you can live with the restrictions of Array then this is an easy way to inherit a lot of functionality without coding. Otherwise you need to implement your own `reduce()`